# Capture information string output of MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE while coding in Java

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file

MySQL documentation says:

> When the LOAD DATA INFILE statement finishes, it returns an information string in the following format:
>
> Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Now, I want to get this information string when I execute Load Data Infile through my Java code. This is needed as I have to tally the number of inserts made into the table to make sure that we do not miss any record. Note that my Java code is all right, I need to know how to capture this string.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use executeUpdate();

Try this

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/foobar", "root", "password");

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = 
    "load data infile 'c:/temp/some_data.txt' \n" +
    "   replace \n" +
    "   into table prd \n" +
    "   columns terminated by '\\t' \n" +
    "   ignore 1 lines";

int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

System.out.println("Rows: " + rows);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following will work through JDBC. Note that to use LOAD DATA INFILE you need superuser privilege. Which you don't need for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/foobar", "root", "password");

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = 
    "load data infile 'c:/temp/some_data.txt' \n" +
    "   replace \n" +
    "   into table prd \n" +
    "   columns terminated by '\\t' \n" +
    "   ignore 1 lines";
stmt.execute(sql);
```

Comment: That is not my question. "Load data infile" works just fine. I need to capture the output which is generated when you run it with "source c:/temp/some_data.txt" on MySQL prompt.